# Interesting Value When Not Initialized to 0

Tags: c, gcc, initialization, codeblocks, kernighan-and-ritchie

I have the following code which is supposed to display each input word on a separate line. For kicks, I placed a `printf` to display the word count after every word to make sure I understood the logic.

```
#include <stdio.h>

/*Write a program that prints its input one word per line*/

#define IN 1
#define OUT 0

int main()
{
    int c, state, wordcount;

    state = OUT;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) 
    {
        if (c == ' ' || c == '\t' || c == '\n') 
        {
            if (state == IN)
            {
                printf("\n");
                printf("Current word count: %i\n", wordcount); 
                /*troubleshooting*/
                state = OUT;
            }
        }
        else if (state == OUT) 
        {
            state = IN;
            putchar(c);
            ++wordcount;
        }
        else
        {
            putchar(c);
        }
    }
}
```

The output for this is shown in this picture. For some reason, without initializing the wordcount variable initially to 0, it starts at 9.

[Wordcount variable gets set to 9 when it is not initialized to 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AG9Td.png)

When initializing the wordcount variable to 0 (just setting wordcount = 0 in the int declaration statement), everything works as expected:

[Wordcount variable is correct when initialized to 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9x5M1.png)

Can someone explain to me what is going on here? Does this have something to do with how these variables are stored in memory? Trying to understand what is going on. Thanks!

Comment: What's `inside `? `state` has not been initialized.

Comment: Undefined behaviour.

Comment: You want the pure C explanation or the explanation that pertains to how C is compiled on your machine?

Comment: It's undefined behavior.  It is generally of little interest, and certainly not something to post here about.

Comment: I meant to change that "inside" to be "state" - must have missed that one. I updated the code accordingly. Tom...I ask because I don't understand why I am getting this behavior - that's what forums and questions are for.

Comment: @DerekZhongXuanKwok You're getting it because you can get anything.  It's undefined.  Anything beyond that is implementation-specific and can change without notice.  A new machine, a new compiler, new libraries, almost anything can cause it to change.

Comment: @TomKarzes So you mean that the fact that I am getting 9 here is because of my current setup. So if I were to try this on a different computer, I might have a different starting value for the variable? Am I understanding this correctly? Thanks!

Comment: @DerekZhongXuanKwok Right.  The specific behavior you're seeing is not specified by the C standard.  If you *really* want to understand it, then look at the assembly code.  In either case, fix your code so that it doesn't happen.

Answer (score 2):

**Before the OP edited the question:**

This is Undefined Behavior.

```
if (state == IN)
//Some code
else if (state == OUT)
//Some code
```

It looks like `State` is not initialized (or set to a value) before comparing it.
Leaving a value uninitialized is not Undefined Behavior, but accessing this way is definitely way to get in horrors of UB!

In **C89**, see **section 6.5.7 Initialization**.

> If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is indeterminate. If an object that has static storage duration is not initialized explicitly, it is initialized implicitly as if every member that has arithmetic type were assigned 0 and every member that has pointer type were assigned a null pointer constant

In **C99**, see **section 6.7.8 Initialization**

> If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is indeterminate. If an object that has static storage duration is not initialized explicitly, then: 
>   — if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer; 
>   — if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or unsigned) zero; 
>   — if it is an aggregate, every member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules; 
>   — if it is a union, the first named member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules.

Refer [standard section **6.3.2.1p2**](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1):

> If the lvalue designates an object of automatic storage duration that could have been declared with the register storage class (never had its address taken), and that object is uninitialized (not declared with an initializer and no assignment to it has been performed prior to use), the behavior is undefined.

According to **C99** Standard, its "indeterminate value", it is either an unspecified value or a trap representation.

But, before you get into the minors details these standards provide, you should acquire some of the most common and good-to-know coding habits. This can be a good start.

---

After the edit from OP:

I ran the exact same code from OP which has `state = OUT;` i.e. `State` initialized, it behaves the way it should.

stdin:

```
Lazy Frog
```

Output:

```
Lazy
Current word count: 1
Frog
Current word count: 2
```

Comment: My bad - I changed the variable name from "inside" to "state" and must have missed the initial assignment. The same thing still happens even when state is initialized with my OUT macro.

Comment: By that last sentence, would always initializing an automatic variable explicitly fall under the 'good-to-know' coding habits? I am a noobie, so just trying to get my head around all this.

Comment: @DerekZhongXuanKwok: It would depend. Sometimes, some compilers don't catch some of these issues with uninitialized variables. Obviously, compiling a code with warnings suppressed is another issue. So, I usually keep my variables initialized, and compile my code with warnings enabled.

Comment: Gotcha. Yea, I am using Codeblocks which has a GCC compiler that comes with it. I did not get any warning when I built my code (warnings are enabled), but it still starts off at 9. No idea how you got it to work without changing my code edits. I guess this is just a matter of my setup/how my system deals with the undefined variable?

Comment: Additionally, the reason I blatantly said that "It depends", because thats would I'd do for older compilers. For, C99 it allows us to declare variable when you have an actual sensible value for it, so that you don't have to initialize it, you just have to assign the sensible value to it. As I said, it depends.

Comment: @DerekZhongXuanKwok: I used the code which has `state = OUT;`.

Comment: Very good effort on the answer, any reason you are not citing the C11 draft? [C11 Draft (n1570)](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html)?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: Oh, sorry, in fact I did. "Refer standard section 6.3.2.1p2:" (which I linked now to the link you provided, thanks!) That refers to the same section. (Please note: Previous comment deleted)

Comment: Not a big deal at all. It's just the most recent standard is generally what is cited. Especially when you consider the C89 standard in nearing 29 years old.... (I'd wager a majority of the new programmers we see here were not even alive then `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: Indeed. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you initialize a variable, it gets a "random" (unused) allocation in your RAM, if something has been already written there, the variable uses this value for itself.

That's why you always declare variables.

The backend is a bit more complicated, but thats the "simple" explanation.